# Получить return code от программы вначале конвейера

Tags: linux, bash, shell, return

Есть программа `pg_basebackup` которая перенаправляет свой stdout в stdin другой программы (архиватор).

Если выполнить запрос return code в конце, то получим результат работы `pigz`

```sh
pg_basebackup -d postgres:1@127.0.0.1 -D - -Ft -Xf -P -l backup | pigz -9 > /var/backups/backup.tar.gz | echo $?"
```

Вопрос как получить return code от `pg_basebackup`, используя Bash?

Comment: `set -e` в скрипте или запуск через интерпретатор с этим ключом: `sh -e ...`

Comment: `pg_basebackup -x --write-recovery-conf --format=t -z -Z 9 --pgdata=$BACKPATH$($DATE)/pg_basebackup/ ` сразу сжатый бакуп

Comment: С помощью чего будет сжиматься бэкап при таких ключах?

Comment: С помощью zlib, очевидно.

Comment: Разве zlib может работать параллельно? pigz именно с этой целью и используется

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В моем конкретном случае разницы нет кто сломался в конвейере, поэтому set -eo pipefail; в начале для меня вполне подходит. 
Как только кто-то ломается в конвейере я получаю return и останавливаю работу скрипта. 
Всем спасибо за советы.

Answer (score 7):

В обычном `sh` это сделать сложно.  В `bash` же
есть массив `PIPESTATUS`, из которого можно достать нужные
значения:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

( exit 7 ) | ( exit 2 )

echo "first: ${PIPESTATUS[0]}, second: ${PIPESTATUS[1]}"
# Output:
#
#   first: 7, second: 2
```

Comment: Да ну неужели?! `set -e` или `sh -e ...` даст желаемый результат

Comment: А причём тут `set -e`?  Задача в том, чтобы выяснить статус, а не прервать пайп.

Comment: @Ainar-G О, какая крутая хреновина! Спасибо! Жаль что в zsh такое не завезли.

Comment: @Oxyd Врёти.  У вас оно [`pipestatus`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Parameters-Set-By-The-Shell), маленькими.

Comment: @Ainar-G Поубивав-бы! © ;-) И массив не с нуля, а с единицы начинается...

Comment: Объясните мне сакральный смысл запуска конвейера, который состоит из уже поломанных запусков других программ? Или вы ожидаете радость от архива, в котором мусор или вовсе пусто?

Comment: @Oxyd, bash'измы -- зло. Да и вообще -измы в shell-программировании чреваты...

Comment: 0andriy Как я понял, ТС и хочет отловить поломанный запуск, поймав ненулевой код возврата первого элемента в пайпе. К сожалению мы имеем то что имеем и *измы имеют место быть.